# Three states in one line state check? (regarding Java syntax)

Tags: java, if-statement

That the code snippet

```
if (addMore) {
    y = x + moreValue;
} else {
    y = x;
}
```

can be compressed into:

```
y = (addMore ? x + moreValue : x);
```

Is familiar to most programmers with a some experience with Java.
But I was wondering if more than two states can be compressed into one line, eg:

```
if (addMore) {
    y = x + moreValue;
} else if (50 < x) {
    y = 50;
} else {
    y = x;
}
```

How can this (if possible that is) be compressed into one statement, something like:

```
y = (addMore ? x + moreValue {SOMETHING IN HERE} : x);
```

Comment: Leave your if statements as they are. They're much more readable than nested ternary expressions.

Comment: Yes, you can, but why would you want to?  Chances are it'll execute exactly the same code but it'll be far harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use such a construct regurarly, it is reminiscent of Clojure's `cond`:

```
y = 
  addMore ? x + moreValue :
  50 < x  ? 50            :
            x;
```

I find no issues with readabiility, quite to the contrary. I like that I can be sure this whole construct is about assigning a value to y. That is not at all obvious with the classic if-else if combination.

Comment: +1 I agree, I don't have problems seeing how the statement connects.

Comment: In fact, the advantage gets even more pronounced when there are more of these else-parts, like 5 or more. In that case with `if-else if` there's a whole lot of code involved and you must painstakingly make sure that the whole block is indeed all about assigning to `y` and no other stuff besides.

Comment: Frankly, if there are more than 2 or 3 blocks, you'd better use `y = computeValue(x, addMore);`

Answer (score 2):

```
condition1 ? (condition1-2 ? action 1-2: action-not-1-2) : action-not-1
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I was unaware that you could break in up like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
y = (addMore ? x + moreValue : (50 < x ? 50 : x));
```

But as said in the comments, this is far less readable than the if..else statement so I think it should be avoided.

Comment: +1 Thank you, I realize it would be hard to read. I'd say I was more interested in knowing how to do it rather than practising it.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** A infamous proverb..... "**Any fool can write a code that computer can understand, but only good programmer writes code that human can understand....**"

**2.** Its more about `readability` and `understandability`.

But still here is your answer....

`(addMore ? x + moreValue : (50 < x ? 50 : x))`   **// Assign this to y**

Answer (score 1):

```
Using Ternary operator, more than one condition can check.
if First condition is true then compare with second value.

y = (addMore ? x + moreValue : (50 < x ? 50 : x));
```